# Extracting a part of a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, parsing, string-parsing

I know this is an easy question, but I want to extract one part of a string with rails.
I would do this like Java, by knowing the  beginning and end character of the string and extract it, but I want to do this by ruby way, that's why I need your help.

My string is:

```
<a href="javascript:launchRemote('99999','C')">STACK OVER AND FLOW             </a>
```

And I want the numerical values between quotation marks => `99999` and the value of the link => `STACK OVER AND FLOW`

How should I parse this string in ruby ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to parse html:

```
> require 'nokogiri'
> str = %q[<a href="javascript:launchRemote('99999','C')">STACK OVER AND FLOW</a>]
> doc = Nokogiri.parse(str)
> link = doc.at('a')
> link.text
=> "STACK OVER AND FLOW"
> link['href'][/(\d+)/, 1]
=> "99999"
```

http://nokogiri.org/

Comment: +1 for using Nokogiri, but, instead of `doc.search('a').first` use `doc.at('a')`. Instead of `link.attribute('href').value` use `link['href']`. Instead of `href.scan(/'(\d+)'/).flatten` use `href[/(\d+)/, 1]`.

Comment: I agree with @the Tin Man, but just `link['href'][/\d+/]`

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. To understand more, can you please explain how does [/(\d+)/, 1] work ?

Comment: `/(\d+)/` is a regular expression which matchs any sequence of digits. Using `[/(\d+)/]` on `link['href']`(a string), returns the part of the string that matchs that regex.

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you have only one link in string

```
str = %{<a href="javascript:launchRemote('99999','C')">STACK OVER AND FLOW             </a>}
num = str.match(/href=".*?'(\d*)'.*?/)[1].to_i
name = str.match(/>(.*?)</)[1].strip
```

Comment: num returns nil :/
and for the name, how should I exclude > and < chars as well ?

Comment: Previously it was fast written, but now it is tested and working.

Answer (score 0):

Way to get both at a time:

```
str = "<a href=\"javascript:launchRemote('99999','C')\">STACK OVER AND FLOW         </a>"
num, name = str.scan(/launchRemote\('(\d+)'[^>]+>\s*(.*?)\s*</).first
# => ["99999", "STACK OVER AND FLOW"]
```